# Rerender React component when props change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have a react component with a Mobx store that looks like this:

```
class Board extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dataStore.getSinglePlayer(1)
    this.props.squareStore.getAllSquares()
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (
      this.props.dataStore.currentPlayer !==
      this.nextProps.dataStore.currentPlayer
    ) {
      this.nextProps.dataStore.getSinglePlayer(1)
    }
  }

  randomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
  }

  roll(playerId, playerPosition) {
    let dice1 = this.randomNumber()
    let dice2 = this.randomNumber()

    let totalRoll = dice1 + dice2
    let totalPosition = totalRoll + playerPosition
    this.props.dataStore.changeUserPosition(playerId, totalRoll)
    document.getElementById('dice').innerHTML =
      'You rolled ' + totalRoll + '!  You are now on ' + totalPosition
  }

  render() {
    var player = {
      name: '',
      id: '',
      position: 0
    }
    console.log(this.props.dataStore.currentPlayer)
    if (this.props.dataStore.currentPlayer) {
      var currentPlayer = this.props.dataStore.currentPlayer
      player = {
        name: currentPlayer.name,
        id: currentPlayer.id,
        position: currentPlayer.position
      }
    }
    if (this.props.squareStore.squares) {
      var squares = this.props.squareStore.squares.map((square, i) => {
        var movement

        if (i == player.position) {
          movement = **
        }
        return (
          <li key={i}>
            <span>
              {square.title}
              <br />
              {movement}
              {square.price}
            </span>
          </li>
        )
      })
    } else {
      squares = <h4>Squares being loaded...</h4>
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Player: {player.name}</h1>
        <h2>Roll Dice!</h2>
        <button onClick={() => this.roll(player.id, player.position)}>
          Roll
        </button>{' '}
        <h1 id="dice">{}</h1>
        <div className="board">
          <ul>{squares}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default inject('dataStore', 'squareStore')(observer(Board))
```

When the button is clicked this.props.dataStore.currentPlayer.position updates with a new value.  However this new value only shows up when the page is manually refreshed.   Is there a way of telling the component that the value has changed and it should rerender automatically?

Answer (score 6):

[React.Component Lifecycle => Updating](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating)

**An update can be caused by changes to props or state.**

That's mean if you would like to re-render your component, you need to:

- update Component state by using `this.setState({ })` method
- or pass updated `props` to that component from parent
- or if you are using `Redux/MobX` as the state manager, you need to update the store, so connected `props` will be updated and `re-render` would be triggered

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using `state` so you `setState` to re renders your component.
I Would suggest to refactor your code , especially your `render`. I think your player should be the state as some params changes each click (current player id, name and position )..be aware not to directly set your state in `render` cause this may cause infinite loop and `render` should always remain pure method. So this need more serious refactor.
Moreover, usually there is no need to use stateful component where you don't have state or even a constructor!

Anyway here we just `setState` the totalPosition and this MAY work for you, but you should consider to optimize your component .

```
class Board extends Component {
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
 totalPosition: null
 }
}
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dataStore.getSinglePlayer(1)
    this.props.squareStore.getAllSquares()
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (
      this.props.dataStore.currentPlayer !==
      this.nextProps.dataStore.currentPlayer
    ) {
      this.nextProps.dataStore.getSinglePlayer(1)
    }
  }

  randomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
  }

  roll(playerId, playerPosition) {
    let dice1 = this.randomNumber()
    let dice2 = this.randomNumber()
    let totalRoll = dice1 + dice2
    this.setState({
      totalPostion: totalRoll + playerPosition
    });
    let totalPosition = totalRoll + playerPosition
    this.props.dataStore.changeUserPosition(playerId, totalRoll)
    document.getElementById('dice').innerHTML =
      'You rolled ' + totalRoll + '!  You are now on ' + this.state.playerPostion
  }

  render() {
    var player = {
      name: '',
      id: '',
      position: 0
    }
    console.log(this.props.dataStore.currentPlayer)
    if (this.props.dataStore.currentPlayer) {
      var currentPlayer = this.props.dataStore.currentPlayer
      player = {
        name: currentPlayer.name,
        id: currentPlayer.id,
        position: currentPlayer.position
      }
    }
    if (this.props.squareStore.squares) {
      var squares = this.props.squareStore.squares.map((square, i) => {
        var movement

        if (i == player.position) {
          movement = **
        }
        return (
          <li key={i}>
            <span>
              {square.title}
              <br />
              {movement}
              {square.price}
            </span>
          </li>
        )
      })
    } else {
      squares = <h4>Squares being loaded...</h4>
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Player: {player.name}</h1>
        <h2>Roll Dice!</h2>
        <button onClick={() => this.roll(player.id, player.position)}>
          Roll
        </button>{' '}
        <h1 id="dice">{}</h1>
        <div className="board">
          <ul>{squares}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default inject('dataStore', 'squareStore')(observer(Board))
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, thats very helpful but I'm not sure exactly where I should setState for the player then?  If I do it in componentDidMount nothing changes!  Thanks :-)

Comment: don't setState in componentDidMount , better use it in this.roll function when onClick. your code needs refactor.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() => this.roll(player.id, player.position); this.forceUpdate()}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are not quite setting this interaction up correctly. I've not used MobX, but the react way to do this would be to just change the props.  If you had a wrapping component around this that was listening to changes on the store, and passing the data into Board, it would automatically update.  I think this [MobX connect package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobx-connect) will be very useful for you.