# Rendering of component on unsed prop updation

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been wondering if a component gets rendered again if the a prop is updated and its not being used in render method.
I am using Redux and some unnecessary props have been added to the component with `mapStateToProps` of connect method. I know I should remove the prop if they are not used, but before I wanted to be sure if it makes any difference.

Comment: Is everything clear for you now? If so please mark my answer as accepted if not, let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, on default it will/should rerender.

Take a look at this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38678454/9254064

**EDIT:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48609609/9254064

Comment: The given link does not clearly points to my question that is why I am not sure even now. but its was helpful.

Comment: Excuse me, I did not read your question correctly. Please take a look at the second link in my answer. It states that a re-render will only be triggered when the specific props are passed to the specific component.

Comment: Did the last link clarify it for you?

Comment: By unused prop I mean the prop is not used anywhere in the components render method. I don't see anything clarifying in any link that If a prop is not being used it does not make any difference the component will render again if it changes.

Comment: Let me try to explain it better, the second link states that: "if you would like to re-render your component, you need to" following: 
"pass updated props to that component from parent"

This says that IF you want to rerender a component you have to pass the props to the component. This means that a component on itself will **not** rerender if you do **not** pass the props on your own.

Comment: Okay then it means it doesn't matter if it being used or not. get it now. thanks a lot.